# Geth console does not seem to be reading the correct balance

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm running a geth console on Windows with the following command:

```
geth --fast --cache=512 console
```

I've been playing around with Ethereum for a little bit, and want to do a little more. I want to just read the balance of my account for now. My account is:

0x28887D97CcA03df4Ce969726faFD3111e6F7f476

I get the following values:

[image: my eth balance]

This contradicts the amount I know to be in the account, and what reads out on etherchain:

https://etherchain.org/account/0x28887d97cca03df4ce969726fafd3111e6f7f476

[image: etherchain balance]

Any reason why this could be? Is it because I am using fast syncing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast sync, most likely. During a fast sync, balanceOf will apparently return 0 for everything.

Source: I ran into the same issue when I fast synced.